# PHP exec : dirvish default error (23) -- partial transfer

Tags: php, exec, sudo

I have web services that are used for backups, but since the move to PHP7 (?) The backup no longer works.

All web services links work.

I isolated the code that is a problem in PHP 7 but it can come from something else!

```
<?php
//$outputShell=shell_exec('sudo cat /etc/passwd');
exec('sudo /usr/sbin/dirvish --vault L106',$outputShell, $codeErreur);
//exec('sudo cat /etc/passwd',$outputShell, $codeErreur);
    //
    if ($codeErreur == 0){
      var_dump ("ok",$outputShell,$codeErreur);
    }
    else{
      var_dump ("nook",$outputShell,$codeErreur);
    }

?>
```

When I execute this code directly via a browser I have this error:

> dirvish error: branch /san/pcdsi/L106:default image 20190221154124
>   failed dirvish L106:default error (23) -- partial transfer expr:
>   syntax error expr: non-integer argument dirvish error: branch
>   /san/pcdsi/L106:default image 20190221154136 failed

and log dirvish

> rsync_error: *** Execution cycle 0**  rsync: change_dir
>   "/mnt/pc-backup/L106/Users/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
>   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous
>   errors) (code 23) at main.c(1668) [Receiver=3.1.2] rsync: [Receiver]
>   write error: Broken pipe (32)  **Execution cycle 1 *** rsync:
>   change_dir "/mnt/pc-backup/L106/Users/" failed: No such file or
>   directory (2) rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see
>   previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1668) [Receiver=3.1.2] rsync:
>   [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)

If I run the / usr / sbin / dirvish --vault L106 command in root, the backup is done without any problem !!

In addition the part in a comment that I tested via cat / etc / passwd works!

Of course, I checked the rights sudo and the script being launched via a browser www-data is sudo without password ... no problem on this side there

On my old PHP 5 server, this PHP code works!

Do you have an idea? I hold?
- system problem?
- PHP problem?
- dirvish problem on PHP 7 platform?

In short, the exec command `('sudo / usr / sbin / dirvish --vault L106', $ outputShell, $ errorCode);` works in PHP 5 and not in PHP 7!!

Comment: open error reporting in PHP and check...

Comment: Apache php logs are shown above and start with "dirvish error"

Comment: Nobody to answer me. I am blocked because either PHP7 or debian 7 prevents the exec !!

Comment: The sudo dirvish command works on the command line not with the command exec sudo dirvish ... but against the command exec sudo cat / etc / passwd